# React-Router using in search module of application

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, reactjs, react-router

> Question Relatived: `React-Router`,`Link`
>
> Module Bundler:`Webpack`

Because of as possible as fast to rebuild the subject, I have a little time to scan the API of react-router. And some problems came, I am not sure weather i miss such point, but I could not found a good example in official examples that using `Link` component with its props `query` which has `multi Key-Value`. Maybe this description of question is bad, so I take my requirement directly.

Thanks for any help on this.

---

> ⚠ Pay Attention：I use `React-Router v1.0.2`

---

> Requirement：

Here is my component construction：

- search

  - category

    - Front end
    - Backend
  - time

    - within a month
    - within a year

Now, my URL：`...(overlook)/search`

Component JSX:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <Link to={`search`} query={{categories: ‘前端’}}>前端</Link>
        <Link to={`search`} query={{categories: ‘后台’}}>后台</Link>
    </li>
    
    <li>
        <Link to={`search`} query={{time: ‘一个月内’}}>一个月内</Link>
        <Link to={`search`} query={{time: ‘半年内’}}>半年内</Link>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the router:

```
module.exports = {
    path: 'search',
    getComponent: function(location, cb) {
        require.ensure([], function(require) {
            // data fetching here...

            cb(null, require('../components/Search.js'));
        });
    }
};
```

Now, go back to the component construction, to be convenient, I copy it once again.

- search

  - category

    - Front end
    - Backend
  - time

    - within a month
    - within a year

Followings are my hope:

1. When click the `Front end`, my `URL` changes to `.../search?category=Front end`
2. as the same as 1, when I clicked `within a month`, my `URL` changes to `.../search?time=within a month`
3. First to click the `Front end`, `URL` changes to `.../search?category=Front end`, then to click `within a month`, `URL` changes to `.../search?category=Front end&time=within a month`
4. Base on 3, if I click the `Backend`, then the `URL` changes to `.../search?category=backend&time=within a month`(I hope you could realize the change of URL...).

> Solution

It's your turn now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to add some magic to your `<Link>` part.

I mean you need to render the `<Link>` tag dynamically, when you render `search` component, you must have had one function that parse the query of url. It may looks like

```
this.setState({
    category: this.props.location.query.category,
    time: this.props.location.query.time
})
```

When you render the `<Link>` tag, you can dynamical render like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <Link to={`search`} query={this.state.time ? {categories: ‘前端’, time: this.state.time} : {categories: ‘前端’}}>前端</Link>
        <Link to={`search`} query={this.state.time ? {categories: ‘前端’, time: this.state.time} : {categories: ‘后台’}}>后台</Link>
    </li>

    <li>
        <Link to={`search`} query={this.state.category ? {categories: this.state.category, time: ‘一个月内’} : {time: ‘一个月内’}}>一个月内</Link>
        <Link to={`search`} query={this.state.category ? {categories: this.state.category, time: ‘一个月内’} : {time: ‘半年内’}}>半年内</Link>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had do this.But a question come out, when the key-value is unknown amount, it is a big work to set the value of `value`, so , I remember a javascript built-in function Object.assign.  <br/> Like `<Link to={`search`} query={Object.assign(this.props.location.query,time: ‘一个月内’)}>一个月内</Link>`

Comment: That's good, it can merge query params in a smarter way. Is that work for you?

Comment: Maybe I make a mistake in somewhere, the variable this.props.location is changed constantly, and make all the `href` attribution of `A` tag has the same value, I am finding the key.

Comment: `Object.assign({}, this.props.location.query, {time: ‘一个月内’})` assign them to a new object:`{}`

Comment: Yes, you are right.And I just used lodash to copy the object, and it works.But yours is better, thanks